Is there a faster way to find the first value that is not NA in a large vector using base R?
Just like the question says. Is there a faster way to do what is done below when the vector size is very large (> 10M entries) using base R in the general case?
The code below works, but it does not short-circuit, so when the vector size grows it becomes slow for what should be obvious reasons. In this particular example a for loop might be faster but if the first NA value is very far from the start of the vector maybe not...
set.seed(1)
x <- c(rep(NA, 3), sample(c(T,F), size=5e7, replace=T))
min(which(!is.na(x))) #4


How fast is acceptably "faster"? How slow, exactly, does it become and at what vector size? This question is lacking objective metrics by which to answer it satisfactorily.

I and several others who have answered the question think the point is clear. The code above is very inefficient and does not short-circuit when it actually has two opportunities to do so. The excellent answer by Sam_R quantifies exactly what you've asked.

I didn't comment about the point; it's clear what you want, but what's not clear (because they are completely absent) are the criteria here. Surely as the question author you can easily edit the question to include information about the specific point where the vector size growth becomes a problem, and list how fast would be acceptable (even just at an extremely high level like O(n) complexity, if that applies). See [mcve] for more information on what kind of information is needed when you're asking help with solving a problem.

See e.g. What makes a "good" performance question on SO?

I'm going to side with the OP here.  The question is quite clear, and given how straightforward it is, adding more discussion would actually take away from it. Reviewing the accepted answer on the linked meta Q&A, the question checks all three of the criteria listed: 1) it provides a specific goal (base R code faster than what I've got so far), 2) it gives example code that does not satisfy the goal, and 3) it discusses short-circuiting the search and vectorization. I made a couple little tweaks to make those three points a little more obvious. Voting to reopen.

@TylerH I don't see the benefit of closing on the basis that it needs details or clarity after five people have answered and an answer is accepted (i.e. the q was understood). I read the meta question and the one it linked to. Do you think that this needs big-O notation to be specific and therefore on topic? In my view, that would miss the benefit of compiled code being faster than interpreted code (i.e. the advantage of Rcpp over an R loop). Saying it would need to run in less than x seconds with a vector of size y would be specific, but would vary between the OP and the rest of us...

An Rcpp for loop should be fast even if the first non-NA value is not particularly near the start. The basic idea is that you do not need to keep iterating after you have found the first value.
Rcpp::cppFunction("int which_non_na(LogicalVector x) {
    R_xlen_t n = x.size();
    for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (!LogicalVector::is_na(x[i])) {
            return i + 1; // +1 for 1-indexing in R
        }
    }
    return NA_INTEGER; // if no non-NA values are found
}")

which_non_na(x) # 4

Benchmarks
Here are some benchmarks for some vectors of length 1e4 to 1e8 and between 1e3 and 1e6 non-NA values. With a vector of length 10,000 and 1,000 non-NA values it is around 50 times faster than the base R approach in the question. For the shortest vectors, the approach is around the same speed (or even slightly slower than) the pure R nonNA() function in the answer by Carl Witthoft. We see the benefits with the longest vectors and the most non-NA values (so we can exit earlier).
With a vector of length 100 million and 1 million non-NA values, the  median time of the Rcpp approach is around 600,000 times faster than the approach in the question. The pure R nonNA() function falls further behind Rcpp (although it's still decent and only 7 times as slow). The pure R min(which.min(x), which.max(x), Inf) approach by ThomasIsCoding is pretty close with a relative speed of 1.86 compared with Rcpp.
set.seed(1)
nonNA <- \(x) { for (jn in 1:length(x)) { if (!is.na(x[jn])) { return(jn) } }; NA }
results <- bench::press(
    vec_length = 10^(4:8),
    num_non_na = c(1e3, 1e5, 1e6),
    {
        # create vector with non-NA
        if (num_non_na >= vec_length) num_non_na <- vec_length - 1
        x <- sample(c(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), length.out = num_non_na), rep(NA, vec_length - num_non_na)))

        bench::mark(
            relative = TRUE,
            base_r = min(which(!is.na(x))),
            which_min = min(which.min(x), which.max(x), Inf),
            which_1 = which(!is.na(x))[1],
            position = Position(\(x) !is.na(x), x),
            non_na = nonNA(x),
            rcpp = which_non_na(x)
        )
    }
)

Output:
   expression vec_length num_non_na       min    median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
   <bch:expr>      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
 1 base_r          10000       1000     54.2      57.8       1          Inf      Inf  9978    22   193.91ms
 2 which_min       10000       1000      1.63      1.66     36.6        NaN      NaN 10000     0     5.31ms
 3 which_1         10000       1000     53.0      55.9       1.16       Inf      Inf  9977    23   167.24ms
 4 position        10000       1000      2.86      3.11     20.0        NaN      NaN 10000     0     9.71ms
 5 non_na          10000       1000      1         1        51.3        Inf      NaN 10000     0     3.79ms
 6 rcpp            10000       1000      1.06      1.07     47.3        NaN      NaN 10000     0     4.11ms
 7 base_r         100000       1000    326.      353.        1.00       Inf      Inf  3449    83   397.84ms
 8 which_min      100000       1000      1.73      1.73    200.         NaN      NaN 10000     0     5.79ms
 9 which_1        100000       1000    315.      358.        1          Inf      Inf  3366    82   389.22ms
10 position       100000       1000      7.68      8.26     41.4        NaN      Inf  9999     1    27.96ms
11 non_na         100000       1000      2.35      2.52    137.         NaN      NaN 10000     0     8.42ms
12 rcpp           100000       1000      1         1       345.         NaN      NaN 10000     0     3.35ms
13 base_r        1000000       1000   1257.     1514.        1.00       Inf      Inf   223    82   302.37ms
14 which_min     1000000       1000      2.76      2.73    629.         NaN      NaN 10000     0     21.6ms
15 which_1       1000000       1000   1278.     1491.        1          Inf      Inf   226    76   306.97ms
16 position      1000000       1000    634.      643.        2.68       NaN      Inf   917    23   463.92ms
17 non_na        1000000       1000    134.      143.       12.0        NaN      Inf  3787    41    429.6ms
18 rcpp          1000000       1000      1         1      1720.         NaN      NaN 10000     0      7.9ms
19 base_r       10000000       1000  10613.    11683.        1          Inf      Inf    25    25   518.79ms
20 which_min    10000000       1000      3.23      3.23   3493.         NaN      NaN 10000     0    59.41ms
21 which_1      10000000       1000  10445.    10436.        1.10       Inf      Inf    27    27   510.68ms
22 position     10000000       1000    882.      921.       11.1        NaN      Inf   269    22   500.75ms
23 non_na       10000000       1000    189.      205.       49.8        NaN      Inf  1201    42   500.07ms
24 rcpp         10000000       1000      1         1     11100.         NaN      NaN 10000     0     18.7ms
25 base_r      100000000       1000  39833.    39765.        1.01       Inf      Inf     3     6   552.89ms
26 which_min   100000000       1000     10.3      10.3    3955.         NaN      NaN 10000     0   468.35ms
27 which_1     100000000       1000  40767.    40599.        1          Inf      Inf     3     6   555.68ms
28 position    100000000       1000   1020.     1095.       34.2        NaN      Inf    93    21   503.13ms
29 non_na      100000000       1000    211.      230.      164.         NaN      Inf   444    43   500.34ms
30 rcpp        100000000       1000      1         1     40816.         NaN      NaN 10000     0    45.38ms
31 base_r          10000     100000     57.8      74.9       1          Inf      Inf  9998     2   295.12ms
32 which_min       10000     100000      1.53      1.54     60.2        NaN      NaN 10000     0      4.9ms
33 which_1         10000     100000     47.3      50.9       1.93       Inf      Inf  9998     2      153ms
34 position        10000     100000      2.85      2.97     32.3        NaN      NaN 10000     0     9.13ms
35 non_na          10000     100000      1         1        92.9        NaN      NaN 10000     0     3.18ms
36 rcpp            10000     100000      1.06      1.07     85.3        NaN      NaN 10000     0     3.46ms
37 base_r         100000     100000    573.      593.        1          Inf      Inf  2640     5   489.41ms
38 which_min      100000     100000      1.55      1.55    379.         NaN      NaN 10000     0      4.9ms
39 which_1        100000     100000    453.      479.        1.31       Inf      Inf  3453     7   488.38ms
40 position       100000     100000      2.87      2.98    202.         NaN      NaN 10000     0     9.16ms
41 non_na         100000     100000      1         1       578.         NaN      NaN 10000     0     3.21ms
42 rcpp           100000     100000      1.06      1.06    578.         NaN      NaN 10000     0     3.21ms
43 base_r        1000000     100000   5830.     6048.        1          Inf      Inf   244     5   482.78ms
44 which_min     1000000     100000      1.48      1.49   3903.         NaN      NaN 10000     0     5.07ms
45 which_1       1000000     100000   5717.     5937.        1.06       Inf      Inf   261     4   487.61ms
46 position      1000000     100000     13.0      13.3     463.         NaN      Inf  9998     2    42.69ms
47 non_na        1000000     100000      3.48      3.65   1660.         NaN      NaN 10000     0    11.92ms
48 rcpp          1000000     100000      1         1      5784.         NaN      Inf  9999     1     3.42ms
49 base_r       10000000     100000  40802.    40182.        1          Inf      Inf    24     7   367.53ms
50 which_min    10000000     100000      1.85      1.83  22655.         NaN      NaN 10000     0     6.76ms
51 which_1      10000000     100000  40334.    40123.        1.02       Inf      Inf    23    10   344.07ms
52 position     10000000     100000     92.3      91.3     471.         NaN      Inf  9984    16   324.88ms
53 non_na       10000000     100000     20.3      21.1    2043.         NaN      Inf  9993     7    74.92ms
54 rcpp         10000000     100000      1         1     42212.         NaN      NaN 10000     0     3.63ms
55 base_r      100000000     100000 374396.   366226.        1.05       Inf      Inf     3     6   548.73ms
56 which_min   100000000     100000      4.40      4.35  88633.         NaN      NaN 10000     0    21.62ms
57 which_1     100000000     100000 373680.   366947.        1          Inf      Inf     3     6   574.97ms
58 position    100000000     100000    359.      364.     1029.         NaN      Inf  2685    23   500.11ms
59 non_na      100000000     100000     75.7      80.2    4240.         NaN      Inf 10000    38   452.07ms
60 rcpp        100000000     100000      1         1    387345.         NaN      NaN 10000     0     4.95ms
61 base_r          10000    1000000     59.1      63.5       1          Inf      Inf  9998     2   210.55ms
62 which_min       10000    1000000      1.55      1.55     42.9        NaN      NaN 10000     0     4.91ms
63 which_1         10000    1000000     45.6      50.6       1.42       Inf      Inf  9998     2   148.62ms
64 position        10000    1000000      2.85      2.94     23.3        NaN      NaN 10000     0     9.03ms
65 non_na          10000    1000000      1         1        66.8        NaN      NaN 10000     0     3.15ms
66 rcpp            10000    1000000      1.06      1.06     64.7        NaN      NaN 10000     0     3.25ms
67 base_r         100000    1000000    538.      562.        1          Inf      Inf  2801     6   489.45ms
68 which_min      100000    1000000      1.46      1.55    247.         NaN      NaN 10000     0     7.08ms
69 which_1        100000    1000000    432.      456.        1.22       Inf      Inf  3404     7   488.07ms
70 position       100000    1000000      2.71      2.91    185.         NaN      NaN 10000     0     9.44ms
71 non_na         100000    1000000      1         1       520.         NaN      NaN 10000     0     3.36ms
72 rcpp           100000    1000000      1.06      1.07    504.         NaN      NaN 10000     0     3.47ms
73 base_r        1000000    1000000   5571.     5799.        1          Inf      Inf   260     6   481.33ms
74 which_min     1000000    1000000      1.54      1.52   3729.         NaN      NaN 10000     0     4.96ms
75 which_1       1000000    1000000   4557.     4637.        1.29       Inf      Inf   336     7   481.23ms
76 position      1000000    1000000      2.84      2.89   2004.         NaN      NaN 10000     0     9.24ms
77 non_na        1000000    1000000      1         1      5494.         NaN      NaN 10000     0     3.37ms
78 rcpp          1000000    1000000      1.06      1.02   5732.         NaN      NaN 10000     0     3.23ms
79 base_r       10000000    1000000  69156.    69066.        1          Inf      Inf    17     5   377.72ms
80 which_min    10000000    1000000      1.46      1.47  43589.         NaN      NaN 10000     0      5.1ms
81 which_1      10000000    1000000  67884.    66517.        1.05       Inf      Inf    19     5   400.27ms
82 position     10000000    1000000      4.03      4.16  15632.         NaN      NaN 10000     0    14.21ms
83 non_na       10000000    1000000      1.32      1.31  44276.         NaN      NaN 10000     0     5.02ms
84 rcpp         10000000    1000000      1         1     66408.         NaN      Inf  9999     1     3.35ms
85 base_r      100000000    1000000 662166.   619018.        1.04       Inf      Inf     3     4   635.95ms
86 which_min   100000000    1000000      1.90      1.86 326808.         NaN      NaN 10000     0     6.72ms
87 which_1     100000000    1000000 589090.   557688.        1          Inf      Inf     3     3   659.17ms
88 position    100000000    1000000     31.4      31.0   19264.         NaN      Inf 10000     4   114.06ms
89 non_na      100000000    1000000      7.14      7.59  74081.         NaN      Inf 10000     2    29.66ms
90 rcpp        100000000    1000000      1         1     62977.         NaN      Inf 10000     1    34.89ms

Plot of results (log time scale):


I've been avoiding C++ for years. Looks like I have another reason not to now.

Try a microbenchmark for easier comparison.  I just did against the methods proposed in the other answers, you are running circles around them.

@AdaLovelace if you find one let me know - sounds useful! I thought it would be faster - firstly because why would you keep checking once you've met the condition, but also it's the same principle as my answer to this which looks backwards from the end of a vector and breaks early, and that was pretty fast.

I do know (as I once looked at it) that any() in Rcpp Sugar breaks early as you do here --- but I think it won't give us the index.  So your quick and simple loop is likely the winner.

Your table is close to impossible to read because bench::mark insists on mixing units.  Can you maybe turn the comparison into plot?  I know microbenchmark makes that easy.

Good point.  10^8 is larger that (32-bit) integer max aka .Machine$integer.max.  On the other hand we only need the first match to happen before that value ==:-)

@AdaLovelace Others might want to use the function in their production code. Best to always support long vectors in Rcpp code when possible.

@Roland I kinda agree and often use size_t from C/C++ myself.

@AdaLovelace was the which equivalent you looking for this one, written by someone who is (allegedly) no longer here?

@AllanCameron Good find!  Maybe I was thinking of an RcppArmadillo based function.  I really though Rcpp Sugar had one but apparently not.

@AllanCameron I just benchmarked it: it is also slow as it does not 'quit early' on first find.

Sam, and @AdaLovelace  please see my answer, in which the same algorithm as fed to Rcpp runs much faster as a plain R code algo.

@AdaLovelace I've just seen this comment about the table being hard to read. I tried to create a plot but it was even harder to read, even in log scale, because of the huge differences. Where does the table mix units? I set relative=TRUE and I think that everything is relative to the Rcpp method, except the last column which is in milliseconds, but perhaps I'm missing something.

You can use which.min and which.max (without is.na()), since as said in the manual:

Missing and NaN values are discarded.

set.seed(1)
x <- c(rep(NA, 3), sample(c(T, F), size = 5e7, replace = T))

f1 <- \() min(which(!is.na(x)))
f2 <- \() which.min(is.na(x))
f3 <- \() min(which.min(x), which.max(x), Inf)
microbenchmark(
  f1 = f1(),
  f2 = f2(),
  f3 = f3(),
  unit = "relative",
  check = "equal"
)

and you will see
Unit: relative
 expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
   f1 931928.5 596652.0 12690.309 31796.371 33326.273 232.24601   100
   f2 139656.2  98002.5  2770.152  5879.894  8057.321  84.39669   100
   f3      1.0      1.0     1.000     1.000     1.000   1.00000   100


Remark
From the benchmarking, it seems is.na is an expensive operator from the speed perspective, especially when the size of array scales up

Nice.  Could you please add the Rcpp-generated function too?

It's not is.na that is expensive, it is R's promise to check all elements in the vector requiring the loop to visit all N elements.  As the actual question only asks for first match one can do much better.  Similar helpers exist in other languages too as it is both a common task, and an easy optmization to not visit the remainer of the vector when the answer is already given.

This is a very clever answer but it relies on x being a logical vector which I now regret choosing in my example as I also wanted this to work for numeric data. Using which.min() is almost an order of magnitude speed up though.

@noNameTed in that case, you can use !x or x>0 to produce boolean values from numeric values, then apply the same approach as above

@ThomasIsCoding I think you'd lose the speed gain from this nice answer if you did that as R would have to allocate some contiguous memory of the size of the vector to create a temporary logical vector. Did you try the base R Position() or Find() functions? I've never found a reason to use them but this seems like it could be one...

@SamR interesting observation! I didn't use Position or Find before, but seems valuable to dive into

f3 was my first thought for this question since which.min and which.max short-circuit for logical vectors. However, it's relative performance will depend very heavily on x. If the first 0 and first 1 are toward the beginning of the vector, it will outperform the Rcpp version, especially for very large vectors. @SamR's benchmark doesn't do a very good job capturing this nuance. Overall, it penalizes f3 by systematically excluding FALSE from x.

@jblood94 I found it pretty hard to write benchmarks that would run with vectors of these lengths without a segfault. However, I take your point about the exclusion of FALSE not allowing an early exit for which.min(), so I've updated it. This performs much better and I'm prepared to believe that if you can guarantee that the first non-NA would be very early it could be faster. However, when the values in the vector are sampled randomly, the Rcpp approach is still on average faster.

Agreed. Even with vectors of size 1e8, the time difference between Rcpp and your benchmark's which_min is milliseconds at most. It's hard to imagine a use-case where it will make a noticeable difference. The more important consideration is that which_min only works for logical vectors. For the general case, Rcpp is the way to go--I'm not aware of any packages that offer a fast generic function employing short-circuiting to find the first position of x==z or x!=z.

Very late to the party but didn't see anyone mention Position() that does what you are looking for and stops scanning as soon as a match is found:
Position(\(x) !is.na(x), x) # 4


A little faster than using min and base R
which(!is.na(x))[1]

finds the first non-NA value from 100,000,000 values in less than a second, even on a crappy cpu.

I casually benchmarked this against the others and this by far the worst.  Note that in your proposal the whole vector needs to be checked whereas we know we only want the first match.

@AdaLovelace I've used microbenchmark on 100Mill values and this ranked before the min approach.

That claim does not replicate here. I injected your function in the setup shown in the other answer and yours scores about 4.2 milliseconds (and 4.7 for min(which(...)))  in the median whereas Rcpp comes up at 5 microseconds.  Roughly 1000 times faster.  Using which.min() is respectable too at 0.7 milliseconds.

@AdaLovelace That claim does not replicate here. It does since I said "A little faster than using min".

But you are entirely missing the point of OP who wants a fast breaking function that aborts at the first step.  which,min() does that, roughly 5x faster as I mentioned -- and Rcpp does it 1000x.  Are you sure you are adding value here?  I am not.

@AdaLovelace I am not missing any point here! We search a fast base R solution. And this is already fast. So what am I missing?

Not to the OP who asked the question.  Anyway, we are not making progress here and you just keep insisting on what I consider a non-answer.

on an Intel Mac, OS 13.5.2
Edit: retest with purely logical input
 x <- as.logical(c(NA,NA,NA,rep(1,times=20), rep(NA,times=5),rep(1,times=biglen)))
Rgames> microbenchmark(which_non_na(x),nonNA(x))
Unit: nanoseconds
            expr   min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
 which_non_na(x)   691   735.0  1192.88   898.0  1342.5  16088   100
        nonNA(x) 45624 46285.5 47195.47 46569.5 46928.5 102274   100

Dunno how c++ would fare if it ran on numeric inputs but didn't declare "logical.
nonNA <- function(x) {
    for(jn in 1:length(x)) {
        if(!is.na(x[jn])) return( jn)
    }
    return('not found')
}

biglen=1e6
x <- c(NA,NA,NA,rep(1,times=20), rep(NA,times=5),rep(1,times=biglen))

microbenchmark(which_non_na(x),nonNA(x))
Unit: microseconds
            expr      min       lq       mean    median       uq       max neval
 which_non_na(x) 1432.809 1596.131 2398.95178 1606.1205 1615.342 11521.484   100
        nonNA(x)   46.436   47.125   55.06929   47.8625   56.734   111.771   100

biglen=1e8
 x <- c(NA,NA,NA,rep(1,times=20), rep(NA,times=5),rep(1,times=biglen))
microbenchmark(which_non_na(x),nonNA(x))
Unit: microseconds
            expr        min          lq         mean      median         uq        max neval
 which_non_na(x) 322243.196 327702.4310 349913.34584 353146.7080 370955.373 385839.443   100
        nonNA(x)     46.642     48.3305     86.83075    100.3525    115.982    256.817   100


I think what's happening is that x here is not a logical vector so the Rcpp function is type casting which makes a copy. I'd be interested to see whether the results hold if you define x as in the question. Still, this shows that pure R may be a more robust solution if you can't guarantee the types.

@SamR  Looks like you are correct -- see updated answer with another test case

Interestingly this is what Position() does internally (as demonstrated in @s_baldur's answer).

I just updated my benchmark and interestingly although this is similar to Position() it is faster.
